# Erro ao retornar um Array em um método? JAVA

Tags: java

A saída do algoritmo está sendo essa: [D@28d93b30. Eu quero que retorne as respostas de double[] previsaoPeriodos.

```
public double[] CalculoPrevisao(double[] valores){

    double[] previsaoPeriodos = new double[valores.length - 3];

    double alfa = 2 / (double)( valores.length + 1);

    System.out.println(alfa);

    int auxiliar = 0;
    double media = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < valores.length - 3; i++){
        for(int j = auxiliar; j < 3; j++ ){

            media += valores[j];

        }
        media /= 3;

        previsaoPeriodos[i] = alfa * media + (1 - alfa) *  valores[i+2];

        System.out.println(previsaoPeriodos[i]);


        auxiliar +=1;

        media = 0;
    }

return previsaoPeriodos;    
}
```

Comment: O retorno da função é um vetor de double... essa saída é poque não está imprimindo os valores do vetor, assim **System.out.println(previsaoPeriodos[i]);**, você deve está imprimindo assim **System.out.println(previsaoPeriodos);**

Comment: Nesse caso eu vou ter que colocar a chamada do método dentro de um loop?

Comment: Isso... coloque em um foreach... **for(double valor: previsaoPeriodos){System.out.println(valor); }**

Comment: Valeu mano!....

Comment: Por nada meu amigo!!